# What is the best way to access all your projects and their Keys in GCP

Tags: rest, google-cloud-platform

I have a side project in which involves a mobile client and a web client. Users can create GCP Applications/Projects through my GCP account using the web client. The mobile client allows users to search these projects which hold applications to download and use. But to communicate through auth with the projects, I will need their project's keys **without** having to manually get them.

My issue is I'm finding it very hard to see how one would be able to view all projects created from users in my GCP and their information/keys. I will be storing this information in a database available through a Restful API once the user creates the project on the web client. How does one auth against my GCP and access the user's project keys so others can communicate with those mobile client applications as the projects need auth as they use GCP Restful APIs? Is a Service Account the best option in that it will take on a Role to communicate with the GCP APIs without the need for a token?

Comment: Please clarify how your provisioning projects and accounts and keys. You wrote "Users can create GCP Applications/Projects through my GCP account". Does "account" in that sentence refer to your GCP Billing Account? I assume it does not mean your User (or Service) Account. You can enumerate Projects, Service Accounts and Keys for Projects (and Service Accounts) on which you have appropriate IAM permissions. Do you? If you don't, then this isn't possible. If you do, then you can use the API equivalents of `gcloud iam service-accounts list` and `gcloud iam service-accounts keys list`

Comment: DazWilkin, thanks for your comment. Its my personal billing account (for now till I make an organisation). I'm planning on using the RESTful api given by Google to create these projects also as I want to run these creation calls from the Web client.

Comment: 1) You must have an organization to create projects programmatically. 2) Organizations have a quota for the number of projects. You will need to request a quota increase for the project count. 3) Your objectives sound like you are trying to be or emulate a managed service provider. 4) Once a service account key is created, you cannot later access that key. There is no workaround. 5) Storing (duplicating) secrets into a database is a recipe for disaster. 6) I recommend you talk to a Google account representative.

Comment: See @john-hanley comment. You should be careful with your approach. You can create projects without an Organization (as you're doing) but you aren't able to control those projects fully without an Organization. You can likely enumerate the Projects by those associated with your Billing Account but, unless you're ensuring your credentials are added as Owner to them all, you can't access them. Your customers could run amok in there projects and it's on your dime (you're Billing Account pays).

Comment: Hey lads, this information is very helpful and appreciated. It's making me think of much more areas needed. At the moment its all very MVP till I'm able to showcase the project but what you have explained are huge aspects that need to be thought of more. I have found some documentation about creating Service Account Keys and accounts which I'm trying to dig into and understand: https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys#rest

Comment: After creating a Service Account Key, I was able to decode the private key as the JSON file data. Need to be super careful with this but you have cleared a lot up for me.